# How to setup a domain server?

Tags: samba, domain-server

I would like to manage more than 200 ubuntu PC's. So i have a plan to setup a domain server.Can some one explain me on setting up a ubuntu domain server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Samba Server as a domain controller. If you need network manager, I suggest you to try EBox (server and network manager) You can install it from repos by using this command:

```
sudo apt-get install ebox
```

Or you can download and install the new version Zentyal (project name is changed) from their site:

[Zentyal Downloads](http://www.zentyal.org/downloads/)